# import keyboard for python error

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i downloaded the keyboard module for python 2.7 using

`pip install keyboard.`

After installing i tried to import it as such

```
import keyboard as keyboard
```

however it gives me this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from. import _winkeyboard as _os_keyboard
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_winkeyboard.py", line 37, in <module>
    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

my only guess is that i dont have one of these files or i need another dependancy for keyboard. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It's probably a bug. `keyboard` has had a lot of bugs lately. You should report it.

Comment: I think the `.` should not be a part of `pip install` command?

Comment: As for the bug, i will report it. As for the period, i accidentally put that because proper grammar and all that

Comment: I researched some websites, and I think python 2.7 matters. Do you use Python 2.7.13?

Comment: The workaround is to change that line to use `b'kernel32'` instead of `'kernel32'`. Or just upgrade Python 2.7.

Comment: my pthon 2.7 is 2.7.13 which is newest

Comment: Martijn i just got more errors.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from. import _winkeyboard as _os_keyboard
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_winkeyboard.py", line 44, in <module>
    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error = True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be string, not unicode

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Python that was caused in the 2.7 release line by https://bugs.python.org/issue27330 and fixed in https://bugs.python.org/issue29082 . It [exists in 2.7.13](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ef012cc7f7ff8519aba77d8869af70c1a86a98c0) and [is fixed in 2.7.14](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/99ba17f5535ab07d999b302f48457eeb5e9b6840).

`keyboard` triggers this bug [by using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in `keyboard._winkeyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/_winkeyboard.py#L13).

Comment: And for those that can't upgrade: use a bytestring literal like `b'kernel32'` when using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in a module.